# Convert webm to mp3 using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, lightweight-processes

Yes I know that this has been asked many many times, but the libraries on every single answer just ends up needing ffmepg.

The problem with that is that the file size increases dramatically when I include ffmpeg to my project, and I just don't want that.

I want to keep my project as lightweight as possible without needing to add 200 meabytes of data just for video to audio conversion which is just a very small part of the project.

So is there any way to

- 1. not use ffmpeg
- 2. use another lightweight converter with a python wrapper
- 3. just use the parts in ffmpeg where the webm to mp3 conversion is actually taking place

Comment: It is if I can somehow decrease the file size of `ffmpeg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile your own `ffmpeg` using this configuration to decode Vorbis/Opus audio in WebM and encode MP3 via libmp3lame:

```
./configure --disable-everything --disable-network --disable-autodetect --enable-small --enable-protocol=file,pipe --enable-demuxer=matroska --enable-muxer=mp3 --enable-decoder=vorbis,opus --enable-encoder=libmp3lame --enable-libmp3lame --enable-filter=aresample
```

Resulting size of `ffmpeg` is under 2 MB.

Comment: @Andy_ye Very basic instructions are to 1) download the FFmpeg source code 2) run ` configure` 3) Run `make`. What's your OS? You can see some [FFmpeg compiling guides on the wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/#CompilingFFmpeg).

Comment: Is there any chance of a MWE - I have no idea where to start from !

Comment: it's grotesque windows - windows 10 :( what I would do be on a linux platform

Comment: @3kstc Oh...I don't have any experience with that. Maybe see https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds or https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite or https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers or just download a build from https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/

Comment: cheers! on another thought If I were to do this on a Raspberry pi3B+ - how would I do it?

Comment: @3kstc Not sure what you mean. You want to crosscompile on the RPI for Windows? Crosscompile on something for the RPI? Compile normally on the RPI? What's the OS on that device?

Comment: Sorry -  I'm thinking of carrying across the `*.webm` and `*.m4a` on to a raspberry Pi that runs Raspbian on it, and write a small script that can convert the `*.webm` and `*.m4a` files into a `*.mp3` format.

Comment: @3kstc I'd probably just be lazy, `apt install ffmpeg`, run `ffmpeg -i input.webm output.mp3` and call it good.